# Drupal - How to display N nodes of a type X?

Tags: php, database, drupal

How to display N nodes of a type X?

Answer (score 6):

Use the Views module. You'll have a solution in 5 minutes.

Comment: Using Views is the best answer if you want to create a list of nodes somewhere on the site. Views is one of the top 2 modules in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP code, Blocks:

See: http://drupal.org/node/30967 (Display (x) recent nodes (with teasers) of a specified type from a specified taxonomy term)

or

Go to the Admin>Site building>Views
Add a new view
Add a new Block display
Change the style as you prefer my suggestion is to go Under Basic settings change Style to Html List
Add new fields like Node: Title and link the field to the node
Go to the Filter section to filter out the nodes you don’t want displayed.
Go to the Sort criteria and sort Node:Post date